# Integrating a function which cannot be isolated

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

I want to revolve the region bounded by $y=1$, $x^2=y^2+y$ about the $x$ axis. For this, I need to isolate $y$ in terms of $x$. Then, $V = \pi\int^{\sqrt2}_0 (1-y^2)dx$.

Is it possible to set $y$ and $x$ as functions of $t$? Then, how would I proceed?

I also thought if there was something like implicit integration which would let me approach this problem, because you can implicitly find the derivative.

Lastly, is there any relation of the volume with the inverse function, because I know how to find the integral of an inverse function?

Comment: If you're revolving around the $x$-axis, then you'll be integrating over $y$ values.

Answer (score 0):

$y^2+y=x^2$

Add $1/4$ on both sides

$(y+\frac12)^2=x^2+ \frac14$

And finally,

$$y=\sqrt{x^2+\frac14} -\frac12$$

Comment: Never mind this problem, how would you do it if you couldn't isolate one variable.